# merge two arraylist lists in list1 while it remain sorted

Tags: java, arraylist

In my assignment the third step is to Call the method merge to merge the two lists in list1 so that the list1 **remains sorted.**

I write my code but it doesn't work well , the output show wrong because it important to be sorted

```
 public static void merge (ArrayList<Integer> list1, ArrayList<Integer> list2)
 {
        int i;
        int n=list1.size();
        int pos , j=0;

        for (pos =0 ;pos<n ; pos++)
        {
            for ( i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
                if (list1.get(j)>list2.get(pos))
                    list1.add(pos,list2.get(pos));
                else 
                    j++;
       } 
 }
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Comment: @Laf I didn't put the tag (homework ) . some one put it 4 me :)

Comment: @PaulRuane this is for array not arraylist , thanks

Comment: What do you mean? Merge Sort is an algorithm for ordered sequences, however they are represented. BTW an ArrayList is a variable length data-structure that wraps an array.

Comment: @PaulRuane I am still beginner in java , thanks alot for ur precious time :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You only need one `for` loop assuming both lists are sorted:

```
public static void merge(List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2) {
    for (int index1 = 0, index2 = 0; index2 < l2.size(); index1++) {
        if (index1 == l1.size() || l1.get(index1) > l2.get(index2)) {
            l1.add(index1, l2.get(index2++));
        }
    }
}
```

If `l2` isn't sorted, you need two loops:

```
public static void merge(List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2) {
    for (int index2 = 0; index2 < l2.size(); index2++) {
        for (int index1 = 0; ; index1++) {
            if (index1 == l1.size() || l1.get(index1) > l2.get(index2)) {
                l1.add(index1, l2.get(index2));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot , but sorry to bother you but the middle element in list2 doesn't sorted with them .
for example : list1= 1 7 11 13 , list2 = 4 0 25
list1 after merge = 1   4   0   7   11   13   25

Comment: @rain: Added a variant for unsorted `l2`.

Answer (score 2):

Easy fix: sort afterwards.

```
list1.addAll(list2);
Collections.sort(list1);
```

Use sets to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Works but may (sadly) not be what your assignment expects.

Comment: the doctor doesn't teach us this method , maybe he want us to use loops

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void merge (ArrayList<Integer> list1, ArrayList<Integer> list2)
{
    list1.addAll(list2);
    Collections.sort(list1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you merge the lists, call sort method as below.

```
Collections.sort(list1); // carries out natural ordering.
```

If you need a customized sorting, use Comparator object

```
Collections.sort(list1, comparatorObject);
```

Check [Comparator example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/) for more details.

Here is your modified code:

```
 public static void merge (ArrayList<Integer> list1, ArrayList<Integer> list2)
 {
    list1.add(list2); //merges list 2 to list1
    Collections.sort(list1); //natural ordering
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input Lists aren't too long, I'd suggest just merging the lists and using the `Collections.sort()` Method to restore the order:

```
public static void mergeAndSort(List<Integer> list1, List<Integer> list2) {
    List<Integer> combinedList = new ArrayList<Integer>(list1);
    combinedList.addAll(list2);
    Collections.sort(combinedList);
    return combinedList;
}
```

As a sidenote, you should use the `List` interface instead of the `ArrayList` implementation class wherever possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
public list mergeAndSort(List<integer> list1, List<integer> list2){
List<integer> list3;
int list2Size = list2.size();
for(int i=0;i<list2Size;i++){
    list1.add(list2(i));  
}
// Here we got all the elements in 1 list i.e list1

int list1Size = list1.size();
for(i=0;i<list1Size;i++){
    int small = 0;
    for(int j=i;j<list1size;j++){
        if(list1(i)> list2(j)){
            small = list2(j;
        }
    }
    list3.add(small); //Smallest 1 will be added to the new list
}
```

}

Comment: Congratulations on your first answer, @Satish. Your answer would be more beneficial to current and future answer seekers if you gave it a little more explanation.  See [answer]

Answer (score -1):

```
     ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList();
     ArrayList<Integer> b = new ArrayList();
     ArrayList<Integer> c = new ArrayList();

     a.add(1);
     a.add(3);
     a.add(5);
     a.add(7);
     a.add(17);
     a.add(27);
     a.add(37);

     b.add(0); 
     b.add(2);
     b.add(4);

     while( a.size() > 0 || b.size() >0){

        if( a.size() == 0 || b.size() == 0){
            c.addAll(b);
            c.addAll(a);
            break;
        }

        if(a.get(0) < b.get(0)){
            c.add(a.get(0));
            a.remove(0);
        }
        else{
            c.add(b.get(0));
            b.remove(0);
        }

    }

    System.out.println(c.toString());
```

Comment: Generally, answers without explanations are considered not very useful. Please add an explanation.